# What is reason behind the curve shape of Rainbow ?

Tags: optics, visible-light

We see rainbow  during rain but what excites me more that why always rainbow  are formed curve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is rainbow always circular?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199837/why-is-rainbow-always-circular) See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403149), [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72518), [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99297) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23647) for instance. There are many others.

Comment: I upvoted just for emojis in the title. Basically you have 2 vectors in the problem, and the condition to see a rainbow depends on their scalar product looking at a scalar value (Intensity). scalar -> scalar implies azimuthal symmetry. It there were a cross product dependence, that would violate Parity symmetry, unless you were looking at a vector/tensor thing like blue sky polarization.